# Wordpress function parameter syntax differences

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi I just got into wordpress theme development and I have seen many developers when setting the attribute for in for a function in an array use this sintax:

```
'name' => __( 'Portfolio'),   
'singular_name' => __('Portfolio'),
```

I have tryed it and I could not find it any difference then writing it like this:

```
'name' => 'Portfolio',   
'singular_name' => 'Portfolio',
```

Aldo I am a total beginner in both php and wordpress so maybe that's why.

So is there a difference beetween the two ways of writing?If so witch is better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the Wordpress method of returning the proper language value through the localization module. Check this link for more details:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Translating_WordPress

Comment: So in other words if I am not using a different dialect or alphabet it is not necesary to use it right?

Comment: Yes, but it isn't a bad idea, as this can make your site accessible to a broader audience.